# When did various PONG systems overflow/crash due to points?

Tags: history, gaming, pong

Edit:
Given the many different versions of the game Pong, which version allowed you to accumulate the highest score before the game would crash, reset, or otherwise not just give you one more point?

Original post...

This screen capture made me think what the highest achievable PONG score really was? That is, on any system, what is the highest countable/displayable score before the counter would overflow and either wrap or crash the system?
[image]

**Update**:

- This screen capture is not *exactly* Photoshopped, but it is fictional: it's from the Pixar/Disney movie "[WALL·E](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0910970/)". Here's a [YouTube clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a6XNtvQopI0) of the scene I took the capture from.
- Why the close votes? Is it not allowed to ask about "any/all" Pong systems?

Comment: Not sure if that's a screen capture at all. But even when ignoring this obvious Photoshop result, for a serious answer, it would need to be narrowed down to what kind of pong on what system, as there where many different and as well different rules (And none I've ever seen allows an 8000:0 score at all)

Comment: "_what kind of pong on what system_" For instance, the first video game we had as kids was a **Videomaster Olympic** which would "overflow" when you ran out of dimples... [image](http://searle.hostei.com/grant/TVPong/VideomasterOlympic.jpg) (taken from [**Grant's vintage TV game (pong) collection**](http://searle.hostei.com/grant/TVPong/index.html)).

Comment: @Raffzahn see my edit: it's not (really) a Photoshop.

Comment: I'd be very surprised at a crash or total game reset; those machines are a bundle of discrete parts of functionality. I can't imagine that whatever keeps score could affect whatever maintains the ball and bats, etc. It's not like with a microprocessor were there'd be a shared global state visible to all parts of the program (i.e. the RAM).

Comment: @Tommy: Indeed, the game we had (which, on reflection, wasn't the same as the image I linked, but  similar) had approx. 10"x8" of fairly closely packed (for the 70s) 74xx series ICs + a TV modulator. Certainly no processor and as far as I could tell, no RAM.

Comment: @KlaymenDK Photoshoped is by now a colloquial term for artificial/manipulated pictures, no matter what tool has been used. And without any doubt, above is not taken from a real Pong. And the close is as there is no all/any Pong. To be meaningful the question has to be about a specific implementation, as there are many variations called 'Pong' by someone, with almost endless rule differences. Without narrowing  this down it's just **way** too broad.

Comment: @Raffzahn yeah I know very well what you mean by _photoshopping_, I was merely saying what's depicted is not "manipulated" as much as it is simply _inspiration_ for my question.

Comment: @KlaymenDK I have a hard time to the value of arguing what kind of product the picture is, as it's a made up anyway, not a genuine one. It is in no way based in reality nor does it prove anything. Thus it is, at best, distracting from the question not helpful nor making a point. If you want to ask a serious question, it's always best to remove all bells and whistles and narrow it down to what you want to know. That way it can as well be helpful to others.

Comment: that is atari 2600 judging by the atari logo and the wood panneling plus general shape of the machine and i belive it locks up at 20

Answer (score 14):

The original Pong® brand arcade machine used a BCD counter for each player along with an extra flip flop for tens.  The machine would end the game at either 11 or 15 points (operator-selectable) but if that were bypassed it could count up to 19.  The General Instruments chip used in the vast majority of electronic tennis machines would play up to 15 points.  When the original machine was created, there was a common off-the-shelf chip to convert a 4-bit binary number 0-9 into a seven-segment pattern, but the segment patterns for inputs 1010-1111 weren't useful digits.  There were no common chips that would display those values as a repeat of digits 0-9.  Since the GI was a custom chip, however, there was no difficulty having a 4x8 ROM which could convert four-bit scores into segment patterns for the numbers 0-15 directly.

I would expect that many microprocessor-based versions of the game would have kept the score as two BCD digits, which would allow values up to 99.  I am unaware of any having made any provision for scores beyond 99, and doubt that any would have been designed in a way that could do so without explicit provision.

BTW, in the original machine, the BCD-to-segment chip is used twice for each player to generate tens and ones digits, but when showing the tens position the bottom bit is forced high while the upper three bits are set to the inverted state of the tens bit.  Since the BCD-to-segment chip doesn't activate any segments for an input value of 1111, the effect is that the tens digit is 1111 (blank) until a player scores ten points, and then 0001 after that.

Comment: Thank you for your positive contribution, it's quite interesting!

Answer (score 1):

There are many versions of Pong.

- The Arcade version seems to be limited to scores **<20**, as suggested by [this image](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8f/Atari_Pong_arcade_game_front.jpg).
- One version on the site of [Grant's vintage TV game (pong) collection](http://searle.hostei.com/grant/TVPong/index.html) shows a game where score is tracked by placing a marker on a physical board, and there are **15** positions.

**Please edit this answer to add more games** (and preferably sorted by maximum score capability)